# GameCenter turn based matchmaking

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I have a question about GameCenter's turn based functionality. The free version of the app will let users create a maximum of 3 matches at a time, and will block any attempt to create an auto-match or invite another player. My problem is the following, what if a player who has no limit of creating matches invites another player who has reached that limit, the game will take place, and i this is not what i want.

Is there any property i can set to the player who has reached the limit of matches ? I know i can create the match and the disconnect the players if the conditions are not met, but this is also something i would really like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Game Center does not support limiting the number of available matches natively. However, to enforce a limit, you don't need to create and then delete matches either.

Track the number of active matches in your game. When a player reaches the limit, stop showing the matchmaking UI (*e.g., your "New match" button could start showing a message box, instead of presenting the matchmaking viewcontroller*). Take a look at how Letterpress does it - when you have 2 active games in the free version, the "+" button presents a prompt to purchase the free version. If you have 1 or 0 active games, it presents the matchmaking viewcontroller.

Letterpress seems to have an oversight though - one can open Game Center and request a match from there. The Game Center app will open Letterpress, which in turn will present the matchmaking interface and allow you to start the match.

Maybe this can be avoided by registering a [GKLocalPlayerListener](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayerListener_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/GKLocalPlayerListener). Implement the [player:didRequestMatchWithPlayers:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKInviteEventHandler_ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKInviteEventListener/player%3adidRequestMatchWithPlayers%3a) method and see if you can show your "Purchase full version" prompt from there.

Answer (score 2):

playerGroup property may help you.
 When the match request is created a property playerGroup can be set to restrict only the players from a group to connect to players from the same group.

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 4;
request.playerGroup = MyMap_Dark | MyRulesCaptureTheFlag;
```

If your game sets the playerGroup property, only players whose requests share the same playerGroup value are auto-matched by Game Center. The value of a player group is arbitrary. For example, you could define different playerGroup values to implement any of the following filters:

A game could restrict players based on skill level. A game that provides multiple game modes could use it to filter players into the specific game they want to play. A game that provides bonus content through in-app purchase could match players who own the same content with each other.

Setting playerGroup to 0 or not setting it at all means that there is not a player group for that match so anyone can connect to anyone.
Please also go through with this Game-Center guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is nothing in Game Center's matchmaking API to limit the number of matches a player is playing in. There is also nothing you can do to prevent someone who has reached your in-game limit from going to Game Center directly and creating a match there, which totally bypasses your in-game limit.

Comment: How do you start a match from the Game Center app directly? I thought that could only be done trough the game (either by showing the matchmaking view controller or programmatically).

Comment: @leolobato Open Game Center and choose the Games tab. Click on a game. It'll show a list of friends who have it installed. Click on one of them, and Game Center will launch your app and trigger the player:didRequestMatchWithPlayers: event (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKInviteEventHandler_ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/GKInviteEventListener/player%3adidRequestMatchWithPlayers%3a)